# What's the exactly amount of bytes for Event HUb Messages?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I know that Microsoft Docs says 1MB

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide#batch-event-send-operations

But to be accurate, is it: **1000000** bytes or 2^20 **1048576** BYTES

Related to Kafka we need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means 2^20 1048576 BYTES.

And you can test it out easily. I use the SDK and send a big size message, you can see the exception below:

[image]